# Apps I use every day marked "unused", and permissions reset

Tags: samsung, permissions

The automatic permission removal of unused apps is a great feature that I quite like (and therefore don't want to necessarily disable for a bunch of apps). However, my phone does not correctly identify unused apps. There are apps I use every day that get their permissions removed every 3 months (seems to be the interval the phone checks).

For example: I use Android Auto which calls up Maps (built-in Google Maps app) just about every day, and every so often, location permission for Maps gets revoked "due to not being used". I use Google Voice (via forwarding) for my voicemail, and permission for contacts gets revoked, etc.

It would seem whatever is supposed to track app usage does not function, and I wonder if there's a way to diagnose/fix that?

Under my Google account "Activity controls", I do have basically everything turned off for privacy, and I hope that's not the issue: (web and app activity -> off, location history -> off, YouTube history -> off, Ad personalization -> off)

As of right now, at least several of the apps that got permissions revoked are listed in the battery usage statistics (from the last charge), so evidently *some* parts of the system can correctly track usage.

Details:

- Samsung A52 5G
- Android 11 One UI 3.1 (using Nova launcher if that matters)

Comment: [Android developers](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/app-hibernation) says (see last para) you can alter the default time. You can try setting it to 1000ms to see if it works!//If it does increase the threshold value to a laaaaaarge value //I am on Android 12 so can't say if it works on 11 or not

Comment: Of course, this would apply to the whole device and therefore may not be ideal from privacy view - it's a compromise

Comment: @beeshyams your suggestion could functionally turn off the feature by setting the threshold to something like years of time, but I'm looking for why [usage](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/app-hibernation#app-usage) is not detected correctly. I have had permissions revoked on apps I use every day. Is there a way to debug what the current timer value is (then go open an app and see if it resets)? or to debug for example a log of activities that should have reset the timer?

Comment: 1. I know what you are looking for and don't have answers, some other Samsung users reported similar 2. My logic was of that there is a bug in detection mechanism which is triggering this for example daily, trying to increase this to two days for example, can possibly help in fine tuning a figure which is neither turning off privacy control nor hampering your usage//It's a long shot //I was Googling yesterday and saw at least three reports from Samsung users - didn't bookmark them to share

Comment: @beeshyams if the answer is "there is no way" for anyone other than Samsung to fix / debug this, then I would be willing to accept your suggestion of setting the threshold timer as an answer. It would seem Samsung may have "customized" this feature because instead of each app having it's own threshold, it would seem there is just some sort of global scan every three months to put apps in hibernation (unless it hibernates after the correct time, then simply generates a notification only every three months).

Comment: I suspect (no evidence) that it one of Samsung things. For now you can probably try to see if setting the threshold to 2 or 3 days holds as suggested. Meanwhile, maybe some Samsung user or somebody who actually knows can give an authorative answer

Comment: Here's another Samsung user, quoting your question here! https://us.community.samsung.com/t5/Galaxy-Note-Phones/forced-mass-app-perm-removal-turn-OFF-GLOBALLY-Could-have-caused/td-p/2164142

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Nova launcher as well. I'm sure it doesn't have anything to do with this but thought I would mention it in case we see a pattern here...
I ran across this today with some apps that I installed yesterday and I think I may have an idea what's going on here... Galaxy Note 9 still and I'm going to keep using it until I can't out of protest for the removal of the SD card and headphone jack. Lol

Anyways... I received a notification about apps automatically being disabled that weren't used. When I looked at them, several of them were apps that I just used today.
Going through the apps list before putting anything back the way it should be there were three categories, disabled, auto disabled, manually disabled. One that I chose to focus on was Microsoft ToDo.
I launched the app, refreshed the list, and it was still showing as manually disabled while it was running.
I have this listed manually as a deep-sleeping app.
I'm not particularly concerned about that app or I wouldn't have put it there. It was something easy to drill down into.
What it seems like to me is that when you put an app to sleep so that it only runs when you manually run it, The app is listed as being manually disabled and it remains in the disabled status even when you launch the app and have it active.
Since I just updated that app yesterday and used it, and then saw the permissions removed today, I started looking into it and I've come up with a preliminary theory as to what's going on. It still needs some work and verification but I don't have time to dig into it further at the moment. So if I get anything wrong here, any corrections would be appreciated...

From what I can tell, any app that is in the disabled status is included in the list when it removes the permissions. It simply doesn't say so when it notifies you of the permissions removal. Since deep sleeping apps show up as disabled, it removes those permissions. It may do this to sleeping apps as well although I haven't had time to get that far into it.

Within the apps settings, there isn't a separate setting for deep sleeping. It's enabled or disabled. So on another app...Shazam, it was showing all permissions off. It is this today. I didn't turn them off. I keep Shazam in deep sleep. If I want to run it I run it.

Putting it into deep sleep however pushes it into disabled status.(Says "Turn On") and remains so even when I run the app.
Putting it into deep sleep does not change the permissions however. So when I would run it, it ran under the permissions that I'd set for.

When the phone swept for unused apps it saw it as disabled and stripped the permissions. I'm assuming that any app that is disabled when the cleanup runs, including deep sleeping apps, is thrown into the "hasn't been used in 90 days" category and stripped of permissions.

I guess I'll have to wait 90 days to confirm this but every app that I had deep sleeping did have it permissions stripped.
It seems to me that I can't put an app to sleep and have it only run when I want it with permissions set as I want without having it eventually getting the permissions stripped and having to reset them.

Some things that I need to check on later are the "Put unused apps to sleep" feature that "puts unused apps to sleep when they haven't been used in a while" since there's no indication as to what a while means or even what it means to be unused. In "memory" there is an "apps not used recently" list that can be accessed on my phone. I'm suddenly uncertain how that list is utilized, if at all. It doesn't include Microsoft ToDo or Shazam right now. And there's no indication giving any hint on what the relationship between "recently" and "a while" mean. Lol
Basically putting an app into deep sleep it's kind of like putting it in Schrodinger's box. It's both being used and not used at the same time.

This has the feel of an error... One that should have been caught long ago by Samsung. I don't think they intended for deep sleeping apps to have their permissions completely removed when the auto clean up runs but that is what it seems to be doing. It would be great if somebody can verify it.

Comment: I am struggling to see how this answers the question.  There is too much waffle for a start.  Please read the help on how to answer a question.

Answer (score 0):

So, I don't know much about android or coding for it. But I had a similar problem with an app. It was an app that comes up automatically under certain use cases. I'm pretty sure it was a texting app. Well months would go by where I did not click on the app to open it. Only on notifications that popped up, and this would happen to me too. Unless I either closed the app in recently used applications and opened it, or went and pressed on the icon. I know when in the car Android auto can auto connect and give you a notification. Maybe that is why, I don't know I'm just spit balling, but, when I started to open the app at least once a month manually it stopped happening. This was a Galaxy S8 too, I have a pixel 4xl now. But that stopped it for me. Almost seemed like the OS forgot the app was running in the background. It's not an educated guess cause like I said I don't know a lot about Android, or various flavors of it, but maybe it's a similar issue?

Comment: according to the docs linked in the comments, interacting with a notification *should* reset the timer just like opening an app manually. My problem is even with apps I open manually however. I took a trip abroad in January, used google translate a bunch, then in Feb, its permissions were revoked because "I hadn't used it in over 3 months" despite extensive use less than a month ago. I saddened to hear sorta confirmation this may just be a Samsung thing however.

Answer (score 0):

In 2024, `Settings -> Battery -> Background usage limits`  allows one to control which apps should not be put to sleep.

In addition, each app has a setting under `App -> App Info`, called `Remove permissions if app is unused`.